# Recaptcha V3 issues

Tags: html, forms, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

I have tried to implement reCaptcha v3 but when I test (in an incognito window) the form just submits - without being challenged.

Here is the code:

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
 <script>
  function onSubmit(token) {
  document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
 }
 </script>

 <form action="https://URL" id="contactForm" method="POST" role="form">
 <!-- FORM FIELDS -->
 <button data-sitekey="***" 
data-callback="onSubmit" 
data-action="submit" 
id="submit-form-button" c
lass="g-recaptcha btn btn-primary submit" type="submit" value="submit">
ENQUIRE NOW
</button>
</form>
```

I am using squarespace so have had to put the script stuff in the body of the HTML rather than the head - im not sure if this makes a difference or not?

Any advice would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, recaptchaV3 detect if you are a robot or not and if you are not a robot you don't have check the captcha, I don't if that was your question, I hope I helped you. :)

Comment: No ... not really ... I have entered incognito mode in Chrome and submitted the form and wasn't challenged.